# jquery .stop() is decreasing the div's height on each hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a rollover menu and using jquery stop method to prevent the flickering effect that appears when someone mouseenters and moouseleaves very frequently.But after applying jquery stop method and doing the the mouseenter and mouseleave frequently the height of the main menu keeps on decreasing with every mouseleaving and reentering action.It's kind of strange and i am not able to catch the problem.

```
   $("#menu_container").on('mouseenter',function(){
        $("#lmenu").stop().slideDown(250);

    });

   $("#menu_container").on('mouseleave',function(){
     $("#lmenu").stop().slideUp(250);
   });
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? - http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.stop()` which normally works for me without any problem , there is another alternative : ***Check for animation completion***

### Code

```
var hov = $("#menu_container");
var shw = $("#lmenu");
hov.on('mouseenter',function(){
    if(!shw.is(':animated'))
    shw.slideDown(250);

});

hov.on('mouseleave',function(){
    shw.slideUp(250);
});
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54ePX/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
 $("#menu_container").hover(function(){
    $("#lmenu").slideToggle(250);

}, function(){
     $("#lmenu").slideToggle(250); });
```